# How do you code Garson's algorithm in matlab to find the relative importance of parameters when training a neural network model?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am working on a predictive analysis study and came across garson's algorithm but I am facing trouble in programming the formula for it. Here is my code:

```
%%% Data Inputs
inputs = data(:, 1:4)';
targets = data(:, 5)';

%%% Create a feedforward neural network
net = feedforwardnet([10, 15, 20]);

%%%% Set the number of neurons in each hidden layer
net.layers{1}.size = 10;
net.layers{2}.size = 15;
net.layers{3}.size = 20;

%%%% Change activation functions (e.g., 'tansig' to 'purelin' for output layer)
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; % Activation function for first hidden layer
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; % Activation function for second hidden layer
net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; % Activation function for third hidden layer
net.layers{4}.transferFcn = 'purelin'; % Activation function for output layer

%%%% Divide data for training, validation, and testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.15;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.15;

%%%% Train the neural network
[net, tr] = train(net, inputs, targets);

%%%% Calculate Garson's importance
importance = garsonsAlgorithm(net);

%%%% Display feature importances
disp('Feature Importances (Garson''s Algorithm):');
for i = 1:length(importance)
    disp(['Importance for x' num2str(i) ': ' num2str(importance(i))]);
end
```

Here is the garson's algorithm function that I wrote down:

```
function importance = garsonsAlgorithm(net)
    %%% Extract connection weights from the neural network
    weights = cell2mat(net.IW);
    
    % Check if there are bias weights
    if isfield(net, 'b')
        bias_weights = cell2mat(net.b);
        weights = [weights; bias_weights];
    end
    
    %%% Calculate the absolute values of the weights
    absolute_weights = abs(weights);
    
    %%% Calculate the importance for each input feature
    importance = sum(absolute_weights, 1);
    
    %%% Normalize importance values
    importance = importance / sum(importance);
end
```

Is this correct or not?. Also, would there be any sort of variation of outputs (relative importance) when changing the number of inputs in the garson's algorithm?

I have attached the formula for Garson's algorithm for reference:

[Formula for Garson's Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7DZC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of Garson's algorithm appears to be on the right track. Garson's algorithm is a technique used to determine the relative importance of input variables in a neural network by examining the connection weights.

Your code extracts the connection weights from the neural network and computes the absolute weights for each input feature, then normalizes these weights to calculate the importance of each feature.

However, there might be a small issue in the code related to the handling of bias weights. In your implementation, you're checking if bias weights exist using **isfield(net, 'b')**. Instead, you can directly check the existence of bias weights in the net structure as follows:

```
% Check if there are bias weights
if isfield(net, 'b')
    bias_weights = cell2mat(net.b);
    % Rest of your bias weight processing
end
```

Regarding variations in outputs when changing the number of inputs in Garson's algorithm: Yes, the relative importance of features can change based on the number of inputs. Adding or removing inputs might change the network's learning behavior and the relationships between inputs and outputs, which could influence the importance of each input feature. It's essential to re-run Garson's algorithm whenever the network's architecture or input dimensions change to assess feature importance accurately.

Remember, Garson's algorithm provides a relative measure of feature importance within the context of the specific neural network architecture and data. Therefore, interpretation of feature importance should consider the entire context of the model and the problem being solved.